# Boolean From Text File Online

Tags: java, url, boolean

I want to read from a text file online, then check for a boolean within the first line of the text file. I'm using this to check for updates for an application.

Here's an idea -

```
    public static boolean needsUpdate()
{
    URL url;
    boolean needs = false;
    try
    {
        url = new URL("https://github.com/../../blob/master/update.txt");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(url.openStream());

        boolean getUpdate = s.hasNextBoolean();

        if (getUpdate = true)
        {
            needs = true;
        }
        else
        {
            needs = false;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return needs;
}
```

The text inside the file is `update = false` or `update = true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like that:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("https://github.com/../../blob/master/update.txt");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(url.openStream());
    String text = s.nextLine();
    s.close();
    text = text.replaceAll("update = ", "");
    Boolean getUpdate = Boolean.parseBoolean(text);
    //do something with the boolean
} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```